# add a checkbox to the image_field

Tags: 7, media, entities

I want to add a checkbox-field to each image I upload (like the title- or alt-fields) , to set the option whether the theme should render the image as a gallery or not. the value should be saved in the db. `int(1)`

I don't want to install heavy modules for this...

**edit**: but if there is no other option, I take the module :D

is there maybe a strategy I should use to solve the problem? writing a `widget` or something? hooking into the `images_schema` ?

Comment: is every image a node or do you allow multiple images per node?

Comment: multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this with the [imagefield extended](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended) module and a small custom module. After enabling the imagefield_extended module, I add this code to my custom module.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_imagefield_extended_widget().
*/

function MYMODULE_imagefield_extended_widget($element, $extra_values) {
  // If you need the field or widget to conditionally add a FAPI field, use these.
  $field = content_fields($element['#field_name'], $element['#type_name']);
  $widget = $field['widget'];
if($element['#type_name'] == 'occupancy_status' && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_task_files'){
  return array(
    //This will Replace the Textfield with dropdown select for the description
    'description' => array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Document Description'),
      '#options' => array(
         'Occupancy Flyer' => t('Occupancy Flyer'),
         'Personal Property Release' => t('Personal Property Release'),
         'Introduction Letter' => t('Introduction Letter'),
         'Notice of Rights' => t('Notice of Rights'),
         'Miscellenous' => t('Miscellenous'),
      ),
      // this makes b the default value when the value is not set.
      '#default_value' => isset($extra_values['description']) ? $extra_values['description'] : 'Miscellenous',
    ),
  );
  }



   if( $element['#type_name'] == 'property_gallery' && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_gallery_images' && arg(1)!=='add'){


  return array(
    //These are stored in the 'data' column of the cck imagefield's db table
    'revised' => array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Revise This Description'),
       '#default_value' => isset($extra_values['revised']) ? $extra_values['revised'] : 0,
     '#attributes'=>array('class' => 'revise-check')
       ),
    'revisedby' => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#title' => t('Revsied By'),
      '#description' => t('Replace your name with the current name if you are making a new revision.'),
     '#default_value' => ($extra_values['revised']==0) ?  NULL : $extra_values['revisedby'] ,
       ),
       'revisedon' => array(
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => t('Date Revised'),
     '#default_value' => ($extra_values['revised']==0) ?  NULL : $extra_values['revisedon'] ,

       ),

  );
  }
} /*End function */
```

You have the ability to add or modify the filefield or the imagefield field widgets. The only problem that I'm stuck at is making this work for fupload_imagefield.

Comment: I am using d7... is there maybe a strategy I should use to solve the problem?